# Regular Expression For Validating a bank number

Tags: javascript, regex

I wonder if you guys can help me creating a regular expression for validating a bank number.
the number should be 10 digits and it should start with 1111
thanks

Comment: can you please put it in javascript formula

Comment: @qusai0: could you please learn your programming language basics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on those specs:

```
 /^1111\d{6}$/
```

However, I often allow for spaces in scanned input:

```
/^\s*1111\d{6}\s*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions here:

```
if (strlen($number) == 10 && ctype_digit($number) && substr($number, 0, 4) == 1111) { ... }
```

(though regex would be a more expressive as Axeman shown, +1 to him)

Answer (score 0):

If all numbers after 1111:

```
'/^1{4}\d{6}$/'
```

if mixed numbers and alphabets after 1111:

```
'/^1{4}[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}$/'
```

Answer (score 0):

in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$account = $ARGV[0];
if ($account =~ m/^1{4}\d{6}$/) { print "looks like an account number\n" }
```